# CSS3 Arrows with gradients

Tags: css, gradient

I have been searching in goole how to create and arrow and box with css only. I have found an almost perfect example here:-

http://dabblet.com/gist/4639593

How can I change this code so the arrow points left and not right?

I have tried a few things but just get a diamond shape pointing left!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. change `.shape:after`'s `margin` to `-24px 220px`
2. remove `border-top` & `border-right` for `.shape:after`
3. add the following borders for `.shape:after` `border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;` & `border-left: solid 1px #ccc;`

here the final result: http://dabblet.com/gist/5648799